# pygame failure to detect keyup

Tags: python, pygame, keyevent

I am making a simple game with the pygame library. I noticed a strange bug where if I tap one of the arrow keys for direction to move my character, it sticks it moving in one direction. Key down triggers a positive acceleration in the direction you press, and key up resets the acceleration to zero. Checking these values, the acceleration stays positive despite key up occurring. Looking at all of the events, it registers a key down and key up, but pygame doesn't run the code associated with that key up event. It could be a signal problem with my keyboard, but it seems like it might be event handling in pygame. Here is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_x = 1024
display_y = 512

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_x, display_y))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

fps = 30
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

max_velocity = 16
acceleration = 4


def print_to_screen(text, color, x, y):
    screen_text = font.render(text, True, color)
    game_display.blit(screen_text, [x, y])


def game_loop():
    game_exit = False

    lead_x = display_x/2
    lead_y = display_y/2
    vel_x = 0
    vel_y = 0
    acc_x = 0
    acc_y = 0
    tile_size = 32

    while not game_exit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_exit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    acc_x = -acceleration
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    acc_x = acceleration
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    acc_y = -acceleration
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    acc_y = acceleration
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and vel_x < 0:
                    acc_x = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and vel_x > 0:
                    acc_x = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP and vel_y < 0:
                    acc_y = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and vel_y > 0:
                    acc_y = 0

        if -max_velocity < vel_x < max_velocity:  # if velocity isn't max, adds acceleration to velocity
            vel_x += acc_x
        if -max_velocity < vel_y < max_velocity:
            vel_y += acc_y
        if vel_x < 0:  # velocity decay, if vel is less than 0, adds one. no input = slowed down cube
            vel_x += 1
        elif vel_x > 0:
            vel_x -= 1
        if vel_y < 0:
            vel_y += 1
        elif vel_y > 0:
            vel_y -= 1

        if (lead_x + vel_x) < 0:  # looks into future: if past border in next frame, sets x coord to 0, stops motion
            vel_x = 0
            acc_x = 0
            lead_x = 0
        elif (lead_x + vel_x) > (display_x - tile_size):
            vel_x = 0
            acc_x = 0
            lead_x = (display_x - tile_size)
        if (lead_y + vel_y) < 0:
            vel_y = 0
            acc_y = 0
            lead_y = 0
        elif (lead_y + vel_y) > (display_y - tile_size):
            vel_y = 0
            acc_y = 0
            lead_y = (display_y - tile_size)

        lead_x += vel_x
        lead_y += vel_y

        game_display.fill((255, 255, 255))
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, (255, 0, 0), [lead_x, lead_y, tile_size, tile_size])
        print_to_screen(str(int(lead_x)) + ", " + str(int(lead_y)), (0, 0, 0), 0, 0)
        if vel_x > max_velocity or vel_y > max_velocity:
            print_to_screen(str(int(vel_x)) + ", " + str(int(vel_y)), (255, 0, 0), 0, 16)
        else:
            print_to_screen(str(int(vel_x)) + ", " + str(int(vel_y)), (0, 0, 0), 0, 16)
        if acc_x > acceleration or acc_y > acceleration:
            print_to_screen(str(int(acc_x)) + ", " + str(int(acc_y)), (255, 0, 0), 0, 32)
        else:
            print_to_screen(str(int(acc_x)) + ", " + str(int(acc_y)), (0, 0, 0), 0, 32)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(fps)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Here is the event data from the quick tap:

```
<Event(2-KeyDown {'unicode': '', 'key': 276, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 75})>
<Event(3-KeyUp {'key': 276, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 75})>
```

It shows a key up and key down event, not sure why the key up won't register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you check if `vel_x` is less or greater than 0 in conjunction with the KEYUP events. Think about what happens when we're moving to the left (`vel_x < 0`) and quickly press and release `K_RIGHT`, then `vel_x` is still negative so `if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and vel_x > 0:` is `False`, the keyup event is ignored and `acc_x` is not reset to 0.

You should check if `acc_x` not `vel_x` is greater than 0.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and acc_x < 0:
        acc_x = 0
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and acc_x > 0:
        acc_x = 0
```

The same goes for the UP and DOWN keys and vel_y, acc_y.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I included that, but that fixed the problem.

Comment: Heh, I can tell you why you've added that condition. :P If you quickly press left and right without `vel_x > 0` (or in your case `acc_x`), it can happen that the player stops completely and you have to release the key and press it again to move the sprite again. I think it's usually a good idea to check if the player is moving in that specific direction before you reset the `vel`.

Comment: Yeah that was probably why. Seems to work now, I changed some other code since then. Testing what you said if I tap left and right really quick the acceleration gets stuck again like if you tapped one direction quickly. Weird your fix didn't fix that.

Comment: The problem seemed to be that my key up increased or decreased acceleration while the keydown only set it to positive or negative acceleration so it could pile up 2 accelerations in one direction. Now key down adds or subtracts acceleration from the acc_x and acc_y variables as well as key_up so that fixed it. Hope no problems emerge from that.

Comment: Let me know if new problems emerge.

Answer (score 0):

> Remove that keyup block and add this to keydown block:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
    acc_x = -acceleration
    acc_y = 0
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    acc_x = acceleration
    acc_y = 0
if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
    acc_y = -acceleration
    acc_x = 0
if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
    acc_y = acceleration
    acc_x = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm looking for. The reason the movement is so complicated is because I wanted acceleration and movement diagonally. Your code will remove this, and the player won't stop moving when you release all the keys.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for acknowledging :)